# How to split data for LSTM in Keras

Tags: validation, keras, lstm

I have been thinking about the way of splitting the data into training, validation and test sets for the stateless LSTM. For me, the intuitive way is to arrange the original data into the 3D form (batch_size, time_step, variable_number), then randomly split it into 90%, 5% and 5%. However, both validation set and test set have a lot of data points overlapping to the ones in the training set even though they belong to different sequences. I guess it is OK for the validation set, but not for the test set because many data points have been used to build the model. If so, should I randomly separate 5% consecutive data points from the original data as the test set before arranging the original data to the 3D form?

Comment: Can you explain why there is overlap between train, validation and test?

Comment: @sdcbr After arranging the data into 3D form, every sample/sequence in the 3D data is just one data point different from the previous one. Sure they are different sequences, but the sequences adjacent to each other share many data points. Like [
            [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]],
            [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]],
            [[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]],
            [[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]]
          ]

Comment: You could set aside the final 5% of your time series for testing to minimize overlap instead of random splitting. For instance, if you have a time series [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and want to use 2 timesteps as features, use [[0,1], [1,2], ..., [6,7]] for training/validation and [7,8] for testing.

Comment: Or you could try some kind of blocked cross-validation scheme for spatial/temporal data. See for example this reference: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/ecog.02881

Comment: @sdcbr Thank you for your answer! For the stateful LSTM (with 'stateful=True' in the LSTM layer), I think I should set aside some part of the data at the end for the validation or testing. However, for the stateless LSTM the sequences are independent of each other, so I guess it is better to shuffle and split the 3D data randomly.

Comment: @sdcbr I guess I'd better separate two 5% portions (of consecutive data points) from the original data to build up the 3D validation set and testing set.